# Ethnographic research frame types

Tags: ethnography

How to structure a complete ethnographic system? What are the main frames of ethnographic research and what are the major questions associated with it? Do we need artifacts too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The true power of ethnography is in its exploration of the social, team, political, and organizational influences that guide the views and decisions made by humans.

It’s rooted in the principle that individual views and decisions are guided by culture as much as they are by, well, anything else. This is an intuitive stance, and it’s heavily applicable to UX design.

[image: Look at this Framework]

Its somewhere you keep collecting data until you get to the point where you stop hearing new things.

**Capturing Artifacts**

**People:** Include a headshot of the people being observed

**Place:** Capture the general environment that the observation is taking place

**Activities:** Take photos of what people are doing during the observation

**Vibe:** Capture close up shots of non-verbal cues and emotions

**Things:** Take photos of things and objects that they use, show or display

Comment: Thanks, I think that is a good idea @Mike

Comment: most welcome mate